# Punctuating a salutation on a line by itself

Tags: punctuation, letter-writing, salutations

In a salutation on a line by itself, which version is punctuated correctly?

> *Hi, Mr Lawler,*
>
> I am writing to say [...]

> *Hi Mr Lawler,*
>
> I am writing to say [...]

> *Hi, Mr Lawler.*
>
> I am writing to say [...]

Comment: I have also seen semi-colons used.

Comment: For [business letters](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/653/01/), there is a specific format which numerous online references will give you (you're supposed to use a colon). For informal letters, it's ***informal***, which means you have much more flexibility in what you're allowed to do.

Comment: I've never seen semicolons used. That's certainly a horse of a different color.

Answer (score 2):

None of them are punctuated correctly, according to American English conventions, because abbreviations must be followed by a full stop. In British English, no full stop following *Mr* is perfectly fine, however.

According to the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/653/01/), business letter, i.e. very formal, salutations must be followed by a colon (:). And the comma between the title and interjection [depends on whether the noun is being directly addressed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83606/grammar-case-in-a-salutation-greeting) (or as you said: in the vocative case).  So, `Dear Mr. Lawler:` requires no comma because it is an adjective modifying the noun, whereas `Hello, Mr. Lawler:` requires a comma because it is directly addressing the noun.

So, this would be the suggested usage, based on those guidelines:

> Hi, Mr. Lawler:
>
> I am writing to say [...]

The Purdue OWL also mentions a less common format, known as open punctuation, whereby no punctuation is present after the salutation and valediction:

> Hi Mr Lawler
>
> I am writing to say [...]
>
> Thank you
>
> [Your name]

Please note that "Hi" is can be interpreted as somewhat of an informal greeting and should probably be replaced by a more formal greeting like "Hello" or "Dear".

Comment: I find the use of *Hi* followed by *Mr So & So* strange. *Hi* is rather informal, and I would not use it with Mr So & So.

Comment: @Laure I agree. I was thinking of making a note of the fact that "Hi" is rather informal but I never did, since the question was only asking about punctuation.

Comment: I always thought that if we used, say, "Hi, Mike", we'd need a comma after "Hi" or "Hello" because the name is a form of direct address and is in the vocative case. Hmmm. Interesting.

Comment: I think the 'open punctuation' format looks really nice, clean and uncluttered. I don't know whether it would be accepted in formal circumstances, though.

Comment: @whippoorwill You are correct about the vocative case. The OWL only omits the comma for "Dear". I have updated the answer with that new information.

Comment: No period after "Mr" is perfectly fine in British English, and something I encounter and produce every day. The colon, on the other hand, is something nobody at all actually ever does, including the students of the Purdue University I have happened across so far...